# Is there something wrong with this JS?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, switch-statement

I am trying to code the game of chess using JS and p5.js and I have a problem in my code that I have not been able to resolve for a few days now.

Here is the code:

```js
function setup() {
  // some other stuff: init canvas & board, set noStroke()

  let wp1 = new Piece('white', ['a', 2], 'p', board);
  wp1._draw();
}
```

I get an error at `let wp1 = new Piece('white', ['a', 2], 'p', board);`. It is from the constructor. I have plenty of other code in there, but this is the part with the error:

```js
  switch (type) { // "type refers to the third argument, 'p', from the code above
      case 'p':
        this.type = new Pawn(this.color, this.square);
      case 'r':
        this.type = new Rook(this.color, this.square);
      case 'n':
        this.type = new Knight(this.color, this.square);
      case 'b':
        this.type = new Bishop(this.color, this.square);
      case 'k':
        this.type = new King(this.color, this.square);
      case 'q':
        this.type = new Queen(this.color, this.square);
      default:
        console.error(`Expected piece type as a one-letter string, but got "${type}".`);
    }
```

I am getting the error at the bottom even though I am passing 'p' into the function, and, obviously, `'p' === 'p'` so there should be no error. 
I have tried several different approaches to solve this. Firstly, I tried rewriting the code as an `if` statement instead of a `switch` statement, in the following format:

```js
if (type == 'p') {
  this.type = new Pawn(this.color, this.square);
} else if (type == 'r') {
  // same as above but with Rook()
} // ... and as such for all the other piece types
else {
  console.error(`Expected piece type as a one-letter string, but got "${type}".`);
}
```

... and I still get the error!

I've tried replacing the string 'p' with all the other piece types ('r', 'n', 'b', 'q', and 'k') but to no avail.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: If someone needs me to add some code that I didn't provide, I can do that, just comment so I can add it.

Comment: How does the function with the switch get called exactly? What does console.log output at the very top of this function? You need to break after a case.

Comment: @baao, the function gets called as it is in the constructor for ```Piece()```, sorry that wasn't clear. In regards to ```console.log()```, it never gets called in my code, so I'm not sure what you're referring to. As for the ```break``` after the ```case```, I realized this and it turned out to be my mistake. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement.

You need to add `break` statements if you don't want your script to continue executing lines in the switch statement until it reaches the `console.error`.

Like this:

```
  switch (type) { // "type refers to the third argument, 'p', from the code above
      case 'p':
        this.type = new Pawn(this.color, this.square);
        break;
      case 'r':
        this.type = new Rook(this.color, this.square);
        break;
      case 'n':
        this.type = new Knight(this.color, this.square);
        break;
      case 'b':
        this.type = new Bishop(this.color, this.square);
        break;
      case 'k':
        this.type = new King(this.color, this.square);
        break;
      case 'q':
        this.type = new Queen(this.color, this.square);
        break;
      default:
        console.error(`Expected piece type as a one-letter string, but got "${type}".`);
    }
```

This is an intended pattern in using `switch` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a `break;` statement at the bottom of each case. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Currently because you have no break statements, every case will be checked, including the default one.